# Billing Address: how to add 2 new fields easly

Tags: magento2

I need advice. I have to enter two new fields in the billing address form, for electronic invoicing (italy).
is there a module from which I can start to do this?
or do you have an advice to be able to do it quickly and without problems?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

"Without problems" is impossible with Magento. Me too I'm working with "fattura elettronica". I could advice you that I added easily 2 fields to customer_address entity with custom module and custom EAV attributes.
The problem is that these fields are not showed in checkout because checkout is another world, it works with UI component and quote entity.
For this problem I'm working on and I hope to find the solution asap.
For now, i'm using the new 2 fields only for registered customers (they have at least an address saved) and filled manually from admin.

Comment: thank you @LucScu. i am new to EAV and i am trying this way: i started from this bootstrap module https://github.com/experius/Magento-2-Module-Experius-ExtraCheckoutAddressFieldsTest and now the field appeared in the checkout and in the admin area. But the form not saves the data into the database.

Comment: if you done it correctly you could save the field both from admin that from customer account.